# How do I seal an old woodstove pipe in the basement?

Tags: basement, foundation, removal, basement-refinishing, woodstove

We are in the process of renovating our basement and there is an old wood stove pipe left over from a wood stove we removed. Not looking to remove the entire pipe, as it goes through the roof in two places, but we're at the point where we need to remove/fill in this hole, and looking for advice on how to proceed. The pipe enters the basement above grade.

Some pics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQS1K.jpg

I found this answer: [How to properly close a chimney hole in the basement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/how-to-properly-close-a-chimney-hole-in-the-basement), but it's not quite the situation we have (ours is protruding quite a bit)

My first thought is just to trim it a little above flush with the foundation using an angle grinder with a cutoff disc. And then fill it somehow (not sure how). Is this acceptable, or is there a better way to handle something like this without completely removing the entire pipe and re-filling with concrete? We're happy to leave pipe outside the wall as-is if that's at all possible.

[image][image][image]

Comment: I would just put some insulation in the pipe and cap it.

Comment: It goes outside and then it goes through the roof?  That's really odd, can you explain it?   And if it's disused, patching up the roof would seem a good reason to remove it entirely.

Comment: Hi jay613, yes it goes directly outside, the straight up and through the section of roof that overhangs the house. No idea if that was installed correctly - it was like this when we bought the place. It definitely won't be used any more, but patching the roof is a bigger job than we're looking for right now, and there doesn't seem too much harm in keeping it as is.

Comment: r13, any type of insulation would work? Method for capping? Also, we do still need to cut it somehow (it protrudes far too much to allow us to finish the wall).

Comment: What is the insulation material currently in it? How old is the house? This is one case where I _would_ suggest an asbestos test because chimney insulation would be a likely place where it would have been used. Cutting it would likely release a fair bit of fiber, and that's where the danger lays.

Comment: @FreeMan, thanks for the response. Not sure what insulation type is, but it appears to be mineral wool?? The house was built in 1981, I think the stove was installed post construction (Stove model was a 1984), but I have no definitive proof that his was the case. Would asbestos have been present at that time?

Comment: By 1981, I _believe_ most asbestos use was banned or at least shamed out of use. It's still used quite widely (I was surprised to learn), but, of course, those working with it use proper protection now.

Comment: For filling the pipe, any insulation will work. It is just to cut down the cold drift, and potential whistle from the wind. You might find the sheet metal cap like this one (see link), or weld a plate to cap it. https://www.lowes.com/pd/IMPERIAL-8-in-Dia-Galvanized-Steel-Round-End-Cap/1000237493

Comment: Thanks @r13, I'll take a look at caps. Welding would be nice if I had a unit to do it with :). Gonna have to look into whether there is Asbestos as well before we chop it (thanks again FreeMan for your warnings).